# chrome.tabs.onupdated.addlistener doesn't work on cached pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http') == '0' && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        alert(JSON.stringify(changeInfo));
    }
});
```

i have such background.js it nearly works always %99 but not %100

whenever i restart my browser and enter an already accessed web page when browser loads all contents from cache it doesn't fire this chrome.tabs event

but the interesting part is when i click same website from dial speed it doesn't load from cache and calls the "tabs." action

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation

> Not all navigating tabs correspond to actual tabs in Chrome's UI,
>   e.g., a tab that is being pre-rendered. Such tabs are not accessible
>   via the tabs API nor can you request information about them via
>   webNavigation.getFrame or webNavigation.getAllFrames. Once such a tab
>   is swapped in, an onTabReplaced event is fired and they become
>   accessible via these APIs.

and

> If a navigation was triggered via Chrome Instant or Instant Pages, a
>   completely loaded page is swapped into the current tab. In that case,
>   an onTabReplaced event is fired.

Try using the [chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onTabReplaced) event to catch this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced.addListener(function (details) {
   chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function(tab) {
       console.log(tab.url);
   });
});
```

Note: You'll need the "webNavigation" permission in the chrome [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest):

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "webNavigation"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with 25 open tabs using:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    console.log("update: "+JSON.stringify(changeInfo));
});
```

On restarting my browser I received 25 "loading" events, but only 23 "completes".
On restarting my browser a second time I received 25 "loading" events, but only 22 "completes".

I don't think changeInfo.status == 'complete' will always follow a pageload, especially after restarting.

consider using `chrome.tabs.query()` right after your extension loads instead.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
        if (tabs[i].url.indexOf('http') == '0') {
            dostuff();
        }
    }
});
```