# Run onUpdated if onReplaced did not fire or vice-versa?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension that makes a small modification to google search results after it has rendered.

I was originally using the onUpdated event listener to do this, but learned that event doesn't consistently fire because of pre-rendering.  During pre-rendering the onReplaced event is fired instead.  One post suggested implementing both onUpdated and onReplaced listeners, but even then I've noticed there are incidents where both events will end up firing causing the modification to happen twice.

A potential solution to this problem may be to identify when either onReplaced or onUpdated has already run, so that the other does not. Is there any reliable way to do this?

There are a number of articles regarding the onUpdated defect that appears to have spanned over four years, at least.  However, none of them appear to provide a reliable solution.  The status of the logged bug doesn't even seem to have full closure (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109557)

I have also tried using webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded, webNavigation.onCompleted, and webNavigation.onCommitted (inspired by this post: [chrome.tabs.onupdated.addlistener doesn't work on cached pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187908/chrome-tabs-onupdated-addlistener-doesnt-work-on-cached-pages)).  But with all three events, after my first google search, it fires, but then it stops firing for any other search thereafter.

If additional notes are needed, please let me know. I've been trying to resolve this for a number of days now. Thanks for any help/insight you can provide!

Comment: Please describe the exact user interaction sequence that duplicates the issue you are having. Please describe your goal in more detail.  It is unclear what you are wanting to accomplish. What *exactly* is it that you are wanting to detect (and when with respect to the user interaction with the page)? What are you wanting to do once it is detected? A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The title of this Question does not really reflect the problem you are presenting (or at least my *guess* at what your real problem is). Are you really looking for the answer to a question something like: "What event, or combinations of events, can I use to determine that Google search has updated the page?". If so, please state that in the question and provide *exact* user interaction which duplicates the situation*and* both what you want to do and when. For example, are you just looking to know when it was updated, or when an injected content script becomes unavailable?.

Comment: Please include what you have done. Share your implementation, stack trace if any and steps to reproduce.